# How multiple domain can point to same website source code?

Tags: dns, apache-http-server, php, ip, webserver

Here I am looking for solution like as below. I have multiple website those all should point to one common script folder on a hosting

```
"example.com" --> ".../username/home/public_html/"
"abc.com" --> ".../username/home/public_html/"
"xyz.com" --> ".../username/home/public_html/"
```

Is this possbile?
If possible How many ways to do this?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly you can simply use the `ServerAlias` directive in your site-configuration.

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#serveralias

You can also create several v-host configurations in `/etc/apache2/sites-available` that all have the same `DocumentRoot`